# (led)sidenotes and linenumbers are moved up

Tags: line-numbering, reledmac, reledpar

I'm writing a large document, consisting for the most part of passages written in `reledmac`- and `reledpar`-environments. In a twosided part spanning several pages, the argument of `\ledsidenote` as well as the linenumbers are moved up one line. At the same time, this means that the content of `\edtext` of the first line isn't printed in the apparatus, whereas the `\edtext`-content of the first line on the second page is sometimes printed in the apparatus of the foregoing page (not in my sample, which is not large enough).

In my sample, the lineation starts with line number 2, the argument of `\ledsidenote` is printed one line earlier (in the text, you'll superscript numbers in the corresponding line).

The sample is quite large because I need a text with lots of `\Afootnote`s and `\Bfootnote`s which is longer than one page, so I copied and simplified my original text where the problem first arose. I can't use a dummy text, but eventually I've removed all noisy commands. Without the `\Bfootnote`s (`\Xnonote[B]`) and not on facing pages, the text is printed perfectly well. Changing the parameters of `\Xmaxhnotes` and `\setgoalfraction` doesn't help -- at least, I haven't found the right parameters so far.

```
% uses-*- MODE: latex; TeX-engine: luatex; coding: utf-8; -*-
\documentclass[fontsize=11pt,verbose,
ngerman]{scrartcl}
\PassOptionsToPackage{activate={nocompatibility,true},% expansion=false,
  final,verbose=silent}{microtype}
\usepackage{addlines}
\usepackage[main=ngerman,latin,UKenglish]{babel}
\babelprovide[hyphenrules=classiclatin]{latin}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures{Scale = MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Scale=1}
\defaultfontfeatures{PunctuationSpace=1.5% ,Scale=MatchLowercase
}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily,\ttfamily]{Ligatures={TeX,Common}}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily,\sffamily]{Numbers=OldStyle}
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella X}[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]
\setsansfont{TeX Gyre Heros}[Ligatures={TeX,Common}]
\usepackage[noeledsec,% eledmac-compat
noend,series={A,B},noend,nofamiliar% ,parapparatus
]{reledmac}
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts,% advancedshiftedpstarts,
parledgroup,% nomaxlines,
% ,%
            % sidenotesmarginpage
]{reledpar}
\usepackage{uninormalize}
\usepackage{microtype}
\makeatletter
\linespread{1.07}
\firstlinenum{5}
\linenumincrement{5}
\lineation*{page}
\sidenotemargin*{left}
\linenummargin*{right}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator[A]{1ex}
\Xinplaceoflemmaseparator[B]{1ex}
\Xnumberonlyfirstinline[A,B]
\Xnumberonlyfirstintwolines[A,B]
\Xlinenumannotationpositionside{before}
\Xwraplinenumannotationside{}
\Xwraplinenumannotation{}
\Xhangindent[B]{4em}
\Xlemmaseparator[B]{\quad }
\Xafterlemmaseparator[B]{}
\Xcolalign[B]{\justifying}
\Xhsizetwocol[B]{.47\hsize}
% \AtBeginDocument{%
%   \Xmaxhnotes[A,B]{.97\textheight}}
\RenewDocumentCommand{\numlabfont}{}{\scriptsize\selectlanguage{ngerman}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{arabic}
\shorthandon{"}
\nonfrenchspacing
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
    \begin{otherlanguage}{latin}
      % \setlinenum{1}
      \beginnumbering
      \pstart
      \pend
      \pstart% [\subsection% [\emph{finis speciosus
      %       % (76.8--78.8)}]
      %     {\textnormal{\emph{finis speciosus
      %       (76.8--78.8)}}}
      % \subsubsection% [\emph{faenerator gloriosus
      %       % (76.8--77.7)}]
      %     {\textnormal{\emph{faenerator gloriosus
      %       (76.8--77.7)}}}\sectionmark{faenerator gloriosus
      %       (76.8--77.7)}]
      \setline{0}
      [Trimalchio de fortuna sua dicit]
      \frq\textsuperscript{76.8}\ledsidenote{76.8}[...]
      \edtext{quicquid}{\Afootnote[nosep]{Mü., Schm.:
          quidquid Öb.}} tangebam, crescebat tamquam
      \edtext{favus}{\lemma{favus, -i}\Bfootnote{A honeycomb
            (OLD~1a\textsuperscript{*})}}. \ledsidenote{9}\textsuperscript{9}post\-quam
      coepi plus habere quam tota patria mea habet,
      \edtext{manum de tabula}{\lemma{manum de
            tabula}\Bfootnote[nosep]{scil.\ sustuli}}: sustuli
      me de
      \edtext{negotiatione}{\lemma{negotiatio
          f.}\Bfootnote{Business, trade; a commercial
            transaction (OLD~1a\textsuperscript{*});
          ">operatives Geschäft"<}} et coepi
      \edtext{<per>}{\Afootnote[nosep]{add.~Heinsius (Mü.,
            Öb., Schm.)}} libertos
      \edtext{faenerare}{\Bfootnote{to lend money to, finance
            (OLD~2b\textsuperscript{*})}}. \ledsidenote{10}\t{10}et
      sane
      \edtext{nolente<m>}{\Afootnote[nosep]{add.~Scheffer
            (Mü., Öb., Schm): nolente H}} me negotium meum agere
      \edtext{exhortavit}{\Afootnote[nosep]{H\textsuperscript{marg.}
            (Mü., Öb., Schm.): exoravit H}
        \lemma{exhortavit}\Bfootnote{">Active
              for deponent"<, % \cite{
              Schmeling:Commentary% }
          }}
      \edtext{mathematicus}{\lemma{mathematicus\textsuperscript{2}}%
        \Bfootnote{An astrologer
            (OLD~2\textsuperscript{*}); s.~Horaz
            carm.\ 1.11.2\,f.}}, qui venerat
      forte in coloniam nostram,
      \edtext{Graeculio}{\lemma{Graeculio,
          -onis}\Bfootnote{A worthless or silly Greek
            (OLD\textsuperscript{*}, hapax)}},
      Serapa nomine,
      \edtext{consiliator}{\lemma{consiliator,
          -oris}\Bfootnote{An advisor, counsellor; sharer in the
          counsels (of) (OLD\textsuperscript{*})}}
      deorum. \ledsidenote{11}\textsuperscript{11}hic mihi dixit etiam
      ea quae oblitus eram; ab
      \edtext{acia}{\Bfootnote{A thread or yarn; (phr.)\ ab
          \textasciitilde a et acu, in great detail (see
          acvs\textsuperscript{1})}} et 
      \edtext{acu}{\lemma{acus\textsuperscript{1},
          -us f.}\Bfootnote{1a~A needle or pin. b~(phrs.)\
          \textasciitilde u tangere, to be exactly right, hit the nail
          on the head; ab acia et \textasciitilde u, in great
            detail (OLD~1b\textsuperscript{*})}} mi omnia
      \edtext{exposuit}{\Afootnote[nosep]{Scheffer (Mü., Öb.,
            Schm.): exposcit H}
        \lemma{exponere,
          -osui}\Bfootnote{To set forth in words, relate, describe,
          explain (OLD~6a)}}; 
      \edtext{intestinas}{\lemma{intestina,
          -ae}\Bfootnote{colloq[uial] form of intestinum
          (OLD\textsuperscript{*})}
        \lemma{intesti num, -i}\Bfootnote{(pl.)\ The intestines, guts
          (OLD~2)}} meas noverat; tantum quod
      \edtext{mihi}{\Afootnote[nosep]{H\textsuperscript{marg.}\
            (Mü., Öb.)}} non dixerat quid
      \edtext{pridie}{\lemma{pridie adv.}%
        \Bfootnote{On the preceding day, the day before
            (OLD~a)}} cenaveram. [...]
      \ledsidenote{77.2}\textsuperscript{77.2}[...]
      [dixit Serapa] et, quod vobis non dixerim, etiam
      nunc mi restare vitae annos triginta et menses quattuor et 
      dies duos. praeterea cito accipiam
      \edtext{hereditatem}{\lemma{hereditas,
          -atis}\Bfootnote{that which is inherited, the substance of
          an inheritance (OLD~2b)}}. hoc mihi dicit
      \edtext{fatus}{\lemma{fatus =\,fatum
          (s.~zu~fatus)}\Bfootnote{}}
      meus. [...] \ledsidenote{4}\textsuperscript{4}interim dum
      Mercurius vigilat, aedificavi hanc domum. ut scitis,
      +\edtext{cusuc}{\Afootnote{def.~Öb.:
            \textquote{i.\,e., ut videtur, verbum pers.\ kúshk,
              turc.\ kiöshk};
            \foreigntextquote{UKenglish}{Sedgwick [...] and
              B.\,Baldwin [...] defend H's text; cf., following
              B.\,Baldwin, the Turkish for a small Summer pavilion,
              kö\c sk, from the classical Persian kosk (modern kusk);
              Hadas [...] sees Eastern origins}, % \textcite{
              Schmeling:Commentary% }
          :
          casa editio Patavina (1664): casula Heinsius:
          casa tunc Watt: casa adhuc Corbett
            (Schm.)}}+ erat; nunc templum est. habet quattuor
      \edtext{cenationes}{\lemma{cenatio, -onis
          f.}\Bfootnote{A dining hall or dining-room
          (OLD\textsuperscript{*})}}, 
      \edtext{cubicula}{\lemma{cubiculum,
          -i}\Bfootnote{A sleeping apartment, bedroom (OLD~1a)}} viginti,
      \edtext{porticus}{\lemma{porticus, -us f.,
            (m.)}\Bfootnote{A covered walk having its roof supported
            by columns, portico, collonade (OLD~1a)}}
      \edtext{\edtext{marmoratos}{\lemma{marmoratus, -a,
            -um}\Bfootnote{Covered or encrusted with marble
            (OLD~1\textsuperscript{*})}} 
        duos}{\Afootnote[nosep]{Bücheler (Mü., Öb., Schm.):
          marmoratis duos H: marmoratas duas editio
            Patavina}},
      \edtext{susum}{\lemma{susum}%
        \Bfootnote[nosep]{see svrsum (OLD)}
        \lemma{sursum adv.}\Bfootnote{(expr.\ position) Above, on high
            (OLD~2\textsuperscript{*})}}
      \edtext{cellationem}{\Afootnote[nosep]{H (seriem cellarum
            interpretatur Heinsius) (Mü., Öb., Schm.): cenationem
          Scheffer}}, cubiculum in quo ipse dormio,
      \edtext{viperae huius}{\lemma{viperae
            huius}\Bfootnote[nosep]{scil.\ optimae uxoris
          Fortunatae}
        \lemma{vipera, -ae}\Bfootnote{a~A viper or similar poisonous
          snake. b~(transf.\ or in prov.\ phr., as a dangerous and
          unreliable pet; hence as a term of abuse, esp.\ w.\
          implication of malignant treachery) (OLD~a,
          b\textsuperscript{*})}}
      \edtext{sessorium}{\lemma{sessorium}%
        \Bfootnote{A sitting-room, parlour (OLD\textsuperscript{*},
          hapax)}},  
      \edtext{ostiarii}{\lemma{ostiarius}\Bfootnote{A janitor, porter
          (OLD)}} cellam 
      \edtext{perbonam}{\lemma{per- 
          prefix}\Bfootnote{Before adjs.\ and advs.\ it has an
          intensive force (OLD)}};
      \edtext{hospitium}{\Bfootnote{A place in which to stay, guest
          accomodation (OLD~3a\textsuperscript{*})}} hospites
      <\edtext{C}{\Afootnote[nosep]{add.~Heinsius (Mü.,
              Öb., Schm.): M add.~Scheffer}}> capit. [...] et
      multa alia sunt, quae statim vobis
      ostendam. \ledsidenote{6}\textsuperscript{6}credite mihi: assem
      habeas, assem valeas; habes, habeberis. sic amicus vester, qui
      fuit
      \edtext{rana}{\Bfootnote{\textgerman{Frosch}}}, nunc est
      \edtext{rex}{\lemma{rex}\Bfootnote{%
          [% \cite{
            Schmeling:Commentary% }
          ]play on word Malchio =
            rex, or a parasite's patron = rex}}.\pend
    \end{otherlanguage}
    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
  \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
    \pstart
    bla
    \pend
    \pstart[\subsection{Morgenessen (76.8--78.8)}
      \subsubsection{Kredithai (76.8--77.7)}]
    \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages

\end{document}
```

Comment: I have not a lot of time yet, but maybe one of the reason of the problem is that you use paragraphed footnote with long texte (\Afootnote). But an indivdual paragraphed footnote can't be broken, and that cause trouble. Maybe you should look on `footfudgefiddle` setting.

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit hard to look through your example, because the code is pretty unwieldy. Please note that a *simple* [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) (*minimal* working example) is not incompatible with a *long* output (in many cases, removing the `\emph`s and other text formatting *does* help to reduce the noise). Most importantly, make sure to load only the *smallest collection of **packages and settings*** that are really needed to reproduce the issue! Many problems arise from the clash of different packages: therefore trying to simplify your preamble often gets you a long way towards identifying the problem.

[This point cannot be overstated](https://texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl):

> First, preparing a minimum document very often leads you to the answer, without
> all the fuss of posting and looking for responses.
> Second, your prime
> aim is to get an answer as quickly as possible; a well-prepared
> example stands a good chance of attracting an answer “in a single
> pass”: if the person replying to your post finds she needs more
> information, you have to find that request, post again, and wait for
> your benefactor to produce a second response.

## EDIT

I made a MWE – without all the noise in the text *and preamble* - that reproduces your main problem and includes 3 possible solutions.

My text is shorter and doesn't fill the whole page. This is all that is needed to answer your main question(s): `ledsidenotes and linenumbers are moved up` and the critical footnotes in the first line are gobbled.

The other issues at, and around, page break (footnotes overflow etc.) will just follow suit, I believe.

### MWE (reproduces your issues)

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[showframe]{geometry}

\usepackage[noeledsec,noend,series={A,B},noend,nofamiliar]{reledmac}
\usepackage[shiftedpstarts,
%advancedshiftedpstarts,
parledgroup,
%nomaxlines,
%sidenotesmarginpage
]{reledpar}

\lineation*{page}
%\firstlinenum{1} \linenumincrement{1}  % activate this to demonstrate that there's a ghost line at \pstart\pend
\sidenotemargin*{left}
\linenummargin*{right}
\Xarrangement[A]{paragraph}
\Xarrangement[B]{twocol}

\begin{document}
\begin{pages}
  \begin{Leftside}
      \beginnumbering
%
      \pstart
%\phantom{hello}    % SOLUTION 1: keep the paragraph and insert phantom text (prints a blank line)
      \pend
%
      \pstart
Start of the section \textsuperscript{76.8}\ledsidenote{76.8}
\edtext{\textbf{Text with two}}%
{\Afootnote{\textbf{First Afootnote} (tends to disappear)}}
\edtext{\textbf{disappearing footnotes;}}%
{\Bfootnote{\textbf{First Bfootnote} (tends to disappear)}}
and some more text...
and some more...
\ledsidenote{9}\textsuperscript{9}and some more...
and some more...
\edtext{Another critical footnote;}%
{\Bfootnote{Second Bfootnote (in column style)}}
and some more text...
and some more...
and some more...
\ledsidenote{10}\textsuperscript{10}and some more...
and some more...
\edtext{Another critical footnote;}%
{\Bfootnote{Third Bfootnote (in column style)}}
and that's enough.
            \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Leftside}
%  
    \begin{Rightside}
    \beginnumbering
%% Your starting point: the intro text gets an extra paragraph (works with SOLUTION 1)
    \pstart
    bla
   \pend
   \pstart[\subsection{Morgenessen (76.8--78.8)}
      \subsubsection{Kredithai (76.8--77.7)}]
    \pend
%
%%% SOLUTION 2: cram the intro text in the "preamble" before \pstart
%    \pstart[bla \newline\indent bla
%    \subsection{Morgenessen (76.8--78.8)}
%      \subsubsection{Kredithai (76.8--77.7)}]
%      Right side numbered text
%    \pend
%
%%% SOLUTION 3: conflate the two paragraphs and simulate a paragraph break + skip
%    \pstart
%    bla 
%    \newline\vspace*{\baselineskip}    % simulate a par-break + skip
%    \subsection{Morgenessen (76.8--78.8)}
%      \subsubsection{Kredithai (76.8--77.7)}
%      Right side numbered text
%    \pend
    \endnumbering
  \end{Rightside}
\end{pages}
\Pages
\end{document}
```

The obvious culprit is an **empty paragraph**: the pair of commands `\pstart \pend` invoked without any text in between (here l. 26-28) creates the issues at stake.

Specifically, using this kind of paragraph seems to create a "ghost line". A line that is there, and gets the number `1`, as evidenced by the following line numbers –  but which doesn't take up any vspace. Also, all footnotes that ought to be on the first *actual* line are gobbled.

See f.i. what happens if you switch on the numbering for each line (l. 14 in the MWE): the ghost line is now realized and everything falls into place. But you get an empty line.

I don't know the innards of reledpar well enough to say why this is, but such use of `\pstart \pend` without any text is probably simply not intended.

*You'd be absolutely better off losing the empty paragraph.*

Your rationale for the empty `\pstart \pend`, as you wrote in the comments, is: You've written an extra paragraph on the right side, before the right-side critical text starts, therefore you need an other `\pstart \pend` on the left, for balance.
I'm sorry for missing this point in my earlier answer.

So the question is how to get rid of the empty paragraph on the left, while keeping the right-side intro text, and the number of paragraphs balanced.

I propose three solutions – whether they are applicable for you depends on what your right-side introduction(s) need to look like.

### Solution 1

You could leave everything as it is, but feed the paragraph some phantom text:
`\pstart \phantom{hello} \pend`.

**Pro**: The lines and footnotes are all correct now. **Con**: You get an ugly empty line at the top, and I could not make it disappear with the usual approach (`\vspace*{-\baselineskip}` or the like).

[image: correct numbers but empty line]

### Solutions 2 and 3

Lose the left-side empty paragraph; get rid of the extra right-side paragraph (for balance); *simulate* a paragraph on the right where you can typeset the intro text.

One way to do this (**Solution 2**) is to cram the intro text *and the sectioning commands* in the optional argument of `\pstart[]`, which text is then *printed before the `\pstart`*.

```
\pstart[\indent Intro text 
\newline\indent More intro text 
\section{...}] 
... 
\pend
```

Another way (**Solution 3**) is to force line breaks, vertical space etc. *within the paragraph*.

```
\pstart Intro text
\newline\vspace*{\baselineskip}
\subsection{...}
...
\pend
```

Both are ad hoc solutions and may or may not satisfy all your requirements for the right-side layout, but they do fix the buggy numbering and footnotes that you'd get by using `\pstart \pend`.

Note that with solution 2, the intro text is not *numbered* text. If you need to show numbering on the right side, this might be a problem.

Either way, in the final stage it might be necessary to adjust the line numbers manually around the sectioning commands (see the reledmac handbook 5.4.3). You want to use either `\setline{}` (within a paragraph):

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart%
\setline{2}
Text
```

or `\setlinenum{}` (between paragraphs):

```
\beginnumbering
\pstart
Text
\pend
\setlinenum{2}
\pstart%
```

Comment: The empty paragraph was intentional, because there is a short introduction on the right side (the paragraph with "bla" stands for it) which has no equivalent on the left. I thought that the empty paragraph on the left side is simply ignored with `shiftedpstarts`. When I removed it on the right, adding a paragraph at the end, and texified it thrice, nothing changed.

Comment: First: I've got TeXLive 2021, daily updates.
Second: The linenumbers on the right margin are decoupled from the ones passed to `\Afootnote` and `\Bfootnote`. It still prints the `\Bfootnote`s of the first line of the second Latin page (p. 4) at the bottom of the first Latin page (p. 2). The first `\Afootnote` (`\edtext{quicquid}`... isn't printed at all. So, `\setline` doesn't help.
Third: With the empty paragraph, the `\ledsidenote`s are still moved one line up.
Fourth: It works with `advanceshiftedpstarts` as option of `reledpar`, which on the other hand causes problems i`on other pages.

Comment: With `\setline{0}` after the second `\pstart` the linenumber on the right is moved one step down, but the linenumbers passed to `\Afootnote`, which are partly correct without `\setline` are reduced by 1, so they don't match the number on the right margin. Nothing changes on the left margin.

Comment: I've removed all noisy parts, the problem stays the same: `\Afootnote` and `\Bfootnote` ignore the first line, all lemmas are one line up (2 for 3, 3 for 4...), and at the pagebreak, the entries of the first line of the second page are printed on the first page.

Comment: Thanks for your clarifications. Now I understand that you need the empty paragraph (`\pstart\pend`) for balance.
(I missed that error because it got lost in a heap of other (unrelated) errors due to using texlive 2020. Sorry about that.)
I have taken the liberty to edit my answer, taking your comments into account. Now I give a proper MWE and offer some solutions to your *main* question (sidenotes and line numbers are off by 1).